# Find the reason for FTP error?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

How do I find the exact reason for the FTP 500 error - System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized

This happened while doing FTP transfers. All files below 300KB are transferred without error. But only one is transferred with error. How do I find out the cause ? Also, how do
i get the number associated with an FtpStatusCode ? Is the enumeration name for error 500 = CommandSyntaxError ???

This code (in catch section) did not help -

```
catch (WebException webex)
{
    FtpWebResponse ftpWebResponse = (FtpWebResponse) webex.Response;
    if(ftpWebResponse != null){

        Stream stream = ftpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, true);

        string error = ftpWebResponse.ToString();
        string respStream = "";

        try
        {
            respStream = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            streamReader.Close();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("to string " + error + Environment.NewLine + 
        "stream " + streamReader);

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably going to need the code in the try block as well.

Comment: @user1378730 - probably or for sure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 is the code from the FTP server. You can see details on FTP return codes here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes

"500 Series: Syntax error, command unrecognized and the requested action did not take place. This may include errors such as command line too long."

Things to check:

1. Is there a unicode or "weird" character in the file name? 
   Not all FTP servers support unicode. The easiest option in this case- if you're allowed to do it- is remove or replace any non-ASCII characters. Practically speaking, dealing with unicode is very hard with FTP, so if that solution is okay, it's the simplest.
   Alternatively, you can check if your FTP server supports unicode using the raw FTP command "FEAT UTF8". Even so, you then need to send the raw command "OPTS UTF8 ON" to enable it. (My guess is that FTPWebRequest sends "OPTS UTF8 ON" automatically.)
2. Is the file path extremely long?
   This could result in the server's path exceeding the character length limit (ex: imaging if the server's homedir is a really long path).

Comment: Thanks. I will check 1 and 2 to see what is the cause of the problem.